# is having static method returning the class instance (by e.g. id) of non-singleton class bad design?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I said to a colleague that following is bad design, but in the end I couldn't really give any reason why (apart from that in this case there was already a singleton class that kind of was used as "collection" for all these). But in general case is there something wrong with following (only the "static method returning instance of class" -part, not how e.g. interop is handled.) This is just example  of static method, not real code.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    /... other properties, constructors & methods

    // this is only static method
    public static GetMyClass(int id)
    {
        // get it in this case from unmanaged code
        return new MyClass(InteropThing.GetMyClassStruct(id));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `InteropThing` in this case?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. What would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: in this case there was better way to do it (MyThingsStore that i was implementing indexers and enumerators). but in general case i can't suggest nothing better than this.

Comment: @RagtimeWilly : it's something that handles calling unmanaged code. delegate builders etc.

Comment: it is not thread-safe

Comment: It looks dangerous to expose the `set` accessor for `Id` publicly. What happens if it's changed? In particular, what happens when more than one `MyClass` have the same `Id`? It seems like you need some logic  in the setter, not an auto.

Answer (score 3):

From the sample code it looks like you're hiding a dependency with a call to a static class which will makes things awkward to mock and unit test.

Perhaps better would be:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IInteropThing _interop;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public MyClass (IInteropThing interop)
    {
        _interop = interop;
    } 

    public GetMyClass(int id)
    {
        return new MyClass(_interop.GetMyClassStruct(id));
    }
}
```

It also looks like you could be violating the single responsibility principle depending on what else MyClass is doing.

Perhaps a separate class that's sole function is to create the MyClass objects would be a better approach to promote loose coupling and testability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Testing is interesting point that i didn't think of. This interop thing in another topic, but thanks for that also. I wrote in my post "nothing wrong with following" but now i fixed it to match the question title which is my real concern here.

Comment: Bringing single responsibility principle and mentioning separate class for creating them is what I was more after. That is how actually do it.